# Sum the values in respective columns if the value in first column are same in MS Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

Need to get the total sum at the bottom for each value in the first row if they are same.  I tried Subtotal(9,range) but this requires lot of manual work.  I have around 1000+ rows which needs to be summed.

Example of the problem in the picture below. (colored cells)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUM()` with `FILTER()`. `BYROW()` is for dynamic spill array to iterate criteria's.

```
=BYROW($A$13:$A$15,LAMBDA(x,SUM(FILTER(B$2:B$9,$A$2:$A$9=x))))
```

[image]

All in one formula-

```
=LET(
id,UNIQUE(A2:A9),
x,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(id),COLUMNS(B2:D9),LAMBDA(r,c,SUM(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(B2:D9,A2:A9=r),c)))),
HSTACK(id,x))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You were right using subtotals, but I believe you were wrong using subtotals as an Excel function, instead of the Excel complete feature, as described here:

How to start and configure subtotals:
[image: How to start and configure subtotals]

First result, before clicking on <kbd>2</kbd> (in the left margin):
[image: Before clicking]

After clicking on <kbd>2</kbd> in the left margin:
Final result:
[image]